# F5 iRule for UIE - latency on using the persist uie command

Tags: latency, f5, big-ip

we are trying to introduce to our service the F5 load balancer and in order to do that we are developing an iRule that persist session with the universal persistence feature.
but when trying to persist session with the iRule command "persist uie" we are experiencing latency.
the latency can get more then 1000ms...
what seems to be the problem? how can we get rid of this latency ??

please see our iRule code and the logs that we recorded.
thanks in advance

here is our iRule code:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
                if {[HTTP::host] equals "mpi-lb.creditguard.co.il" } {
                                set txID1 ""
                                set txID2 ""
                                set txID3 ""
                                set txID4 ""
                                set txID5 ""
                                set txID6 ""
                                set txID7 ""
                                set txID8 ""
                                # Log details for the request
                                regexp {(txId|token|mpiTransactionId|transactionID)[=>]([0-9a-z]{8}-([0-9a-z]{4}-){3}[0-9a-z]{12})([&< ]|$)} [HTTP::uri] => txID1 txID2 txID3 txID4
                                regexp {(txId|token|mpiTransactionId|transactionID)[=>]([0-9a-z]{8}-([0-9a-z]{4}-){3}[0-9a-z]{12})([&< ]|$)} [HTTP::payload] => txID5 txID6 txID7 txID8
                                log local0. "uri:[HTTP::uri]:payload: txID2:$txID2 txID6:$txID6"
                                if {$txID2 != ""} {
                                                log local0. "persist lookup uie:[persist lookup uie $txID2] $txID2 in uri"
                                                persist uie $txID2
                                } elseif {$txID6 != ""} {
                                                log local0. "persist lookup uie:[persist lookup uie $txID6] $txID6 in paylod"
                                                persist uie $txID6
                                }
                }
}

when HTTP_RESPONSE {
                if {([IP::server_addr] equals "172.16.100.16") || ([IP::server_addr] equals "172.16.100.17") } {
                                # Trigger collection for up to 1MB of data
                                if {[HTTP::header exists "Content-Length"] && [HTTP::header "Content-Length"] <= 1048576} {
                                                set content_length [HTTP::header "Content-Length"]
                                } else {
                                                set content_length 1048576
                                }
                                # Check if $content_length is not set to 0
                                if { ([HTTP::status] == 200) && ($content_length > 0)} {
                                                HTTP::collect $content_length
                                }
                }
}

when HTTP_RESPONSE_DATA {
                if {([IP::server_addr] equals "172.16.100.16") || ([IP::server_addr] equals "172.16.100.17") } {
                                # do stuff with the payload
                                #find the application unique identifier between <uid> and </uid> (5 is the length of <uid> string)
                                set txId [string trim [findstr [HTTP::payload] "<txId>" 5 "</txId>"] ">"]
                                if {$txId != ""} {
                                                log local0. "[IP::server_addr] : persist add uie #$txId#"
                                                persist add uie $txId 1800
                                }
                }
}
```

here are the logs (you can see the latency between 14:16:08 and 14:17:08)

```
Tue Jun 14 14:16:03 IDT 2016  info  cgwaf tmm3[10326]    Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri://CGMPI_Server/CreateTransactionExtended:payload: txID2: txID6:  
Tue Jun 14 14:16:04 IDT 2016 info cgwaf  tmm3[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_RESPONSE_DATA>: 172.16.100.16 : persist add uie #03f72209-754e-4bde-85f6-69cdf4d27526#  
Tue Jun 14 14:16:08 IDT 2016  info cgwaf tmm1[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri://CGMPI_Server/PerformTransaction? txId=03f72209-754e-4bde-85f6-69cdf4d27526:payload: txID2:03f72209-754e-4bde-85f6-69cdf4d27526 txID6:  
Tue Jun 14 14:16:08 IDT 2016  info cgwaf tmm1[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: persist lookup uie:/Common/mpi-lb 172.16.100.16 443 03f72209-754e-4bde-85f6-69cdf4d27526 in uri 
Tue Jun 14 14:17:08 IDT 2016  info cgwaf tmm2[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri://CGMPI_Server/merchantPages/ResponsiveWebSources/images/cvv.jpg:payload: txID2: txID6:  
Tue Jun 14 14:17:08 IDT 2016  info  cgwaf tmm[10326]    Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri://CGMPI_Server/merchantPages/ResponsiveWebSources/images/mastercard_slice.gif:payload: txID2: txID6:  
Tue Jun 14 14:17:08 IDT 2016  info cgwaf tmm[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri://CGMPI_Server/merchantPages/ResponsiveWebSources/images/pci_slice.gif:payload: txID2: txID6:  
Tue Jun 14 14:17:08 IDT 2016  info cgwaf tmm[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri://CGMPI_Server/merchantPages/ResponsiveWebSources/images/visa_slice.gif:payload: txID2: txID6:  
Tue Jun 14 14:17:08 IDT 2016  info cgwaf tmm[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri://CGMPI_Server/merchantPages/ResponsiveWebSources/images/Logo.gif:payload: txID2: txID6:  
Tue Jun 14 14:17:08 IDT 2016  info  cgwaf tmm3[10326]    Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri://CGMPI_Server/merchantPages/ResponsiveWebSources/images/qm.png:payload: txID2: txID6:  
Tue Jun 14 14:18:06 IDT 2016  info  cgwaf tmm2[10326]    Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri://CGMPI_Server/ProcessCreditCard:payload: txID2: txID6:03f72209-754e-4bde-85f6-69cdf4d27526  
Tue Jun 14 14:18:06 IDT 2016  info cgwaf tmm2[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: persist lookup uie:/Common/mpi-lb 172.16.100.16 443 03f72209-754e-4bde-85f6-69cdf4d27526 in paylod  
Tue Jun 14 14:18:07 IDT 2016  info cgwaf tmm2[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri:/CGMPI_Server/merchantPages/nlb/OK.jsp?uniqueID=697536646.622257&lang=EN&authNumber=9125242& responseMac=7e77d7fe857e707ddf1c8990c80da8373f716c79d0ee79b88 f3d898a9ff0afc0&cardToken=1051484189394580& cardExp=0217&personalId=88888888& cardMask=458045******4580& txId=03f72209-754e-4bde-85f6-69cdf4d27526& numberOfPayments=&firstPayment=&periodicalPayment=:payload: txID2:03f72209-754e-4bde-85f6-69cdf4d27526 txID6:  
Tue Jun 14 14:18:07 IDT 2016  info cgwaf tmm2[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: persist lookup uie:/Common/mpi-lb 172.16.100.16 443 03f72209-754e-4bde-85f6-69cdf4d27526 in uri 
Tue Jun 14 14:18:07 IDT 2016  info cgwaf tmm2[10326]     Rule /Common/mpi-lb-irule <HTTP_REQUEST>: uri:/CGMPI_Server/merchantPages/WebSources/images/ssl.png:payload: txID2: txID6:
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that your using regex lookups on the inbound and outbound flows, these are very expensive and time consuming.  Keep in mind that the F5 needs to proxy the data, hold it, extract the flow, perform the regex manipulation and then pass it back to to the egress stack.  If you want to optimise the time, try to find another way to persist data flows.

That said, you can use the timing command to see how much each event processing cycles the iRule uses:
https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iRules.timing.ashx

Depending on the TMSH version your running you should get the stats within the GUI, or by the TMSH command.

Comment: Thanks @kruczkowski for the quick answer and we will use the timing command. also we are aware of the regexp and we plan to move the "txId" to the headers. but if I'm not mistaken we are experiencing the latency after the regexp command has been completed and more accurately the latency is being viewed when executing the "persist uie" command. does this make sense...?